# Once a question has retained one net upvote, is it undesirable for each answerer to upvote it?

Tags: discussion, voting, best-practices

I've been in the habit of upvoting each question I'm answering, but it has recently occurred to me that this may be counter-productive in a collective enterprise such as PSE, since whoever posted the question might thereby be encouraged to disingenuously delay their acceptance of any answer, so as to artificially inflate their PSE reputation.  I'm sure I'm overlooking some factor(s) which would discourage that practice, but might it be possible to specify them for me?

Answer (score 8):

You should up vote any question you think deserves an up vote. Usually this is for reasons such as it fits well on the site, it is clear, etc. I don't think there needs to be anything beyond this. We should be evaluating the posts independent of who is asking them and what may or may not happen with their reputation.

Comment: I'll think it over, but, for now, I can't see it that way:  I've posted an answer, within the past week, to a question that, over the course of 10 or 11 yrs. and 8K views, has received 23 upvotes and 7 answers, and, with its OP having been "seen this week", the answerers may be serving as a cow furnishing the OP with a form of "cash", unless reputation's worthless.  (I'd sometimes considered reputation as a decisive factor in break-point situations, giving an upvote to whichever of two answerers already had the larger reputation, but will henceforth upvote either both or none in such cases.)

Comment: @Edouard Reputation isn't worthless, but at the end of the day quality content is quality content no matter how much reputation is attached to it.

Comment: There 's a patent ambiguity re the question concerned, and a request for clarification of that ambiguity (which resides in its linguistic formulation, that includes a phrase which deviates from standard English rules for capitalization) has as received no response.  (The ambiguity's in a capitalization that hints at a preference for a particular response, made by at least one respondent, that has as yet failed to receive acceptance:  Also, it falls short of the 3-character minimum required for an "edit".)  Consequently, I consider the downvote of my status on Meta rep inappropriate.

Comment: @Edouard Down votes work differently on Meta compared to the main site. Typically downvotes here just reflect disagreement. e.g. the one who downvoted probably disagrees with the practice you are proposing here.